# Difference between B-Trees and 2-3-4 Trees

Tags: data-structures, tree, theory, b-tree

What is the difference between B-Trees and 2-3-4 Trees?

Also, how would you find the maximum and minimum height of each?

Comment: I can't do any better than just add a link to wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-3-4_tree

Comment: not homework, personal revision.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

...a link to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-3-4_tree) *and* a quote:

> *"2-3-4 trees are B-trees of order 4."*

A `2-3-4` *is a* `B-tree`.
It is called 2-3-4 tree because the number of children for a non-leaf, non-root node is 2,3 or 4.
Had it been 6, it could have been called a 3-4-5-6 tree, or 3-6 tree for short.
Since the minimum number of children is half of the maximum, one can just usually skip the former and talk about a B-tree of order *m*.
The order of a B-tree is defined as the maximum number of children a node can have.
In a 2-3-4 tree, as we have seen, the maximum is 4.

It's worst and best-case height is given by the [general formula for B-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_tree#Best_case_and_worst_case_heights).

***Best case***: log<sub>m</sub>n.  *(all nodes are full)*
***Worst case***: log<sub>m/2</sub>n. *(all nodes are half-empty)*

where

- *m* is the order of the tree - the maximum number of children a node can have, in this case, 4 - and
- *n* is the number of entries in the tree

*"B tree can have an order of any number "* - yes, but for a particular subclass of B-trees, you fix that number in advance. It's like talking about butterflies in general vs talking about the [Monarch butterfly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monarch_butterfly). B-trees are a class of data structures, just like butterflies are a class of insects. [Monarch butterflies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monarch_butterfly) are a subclass of butterflies, just like 2-3-4 trees are a subclass of B-trees.

Answer (score -1):

the main difference why b-tree comes into existence is the number of node splitting required in time of insertion is less than 2-4 tree. In 2-4 tree we found sometimes a term called cascade splitting but in b-tree there is no cascade splitting present.

Comment: You can have cascade splitting in B Trees: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_Tree#Insertion